# What is wrong with this function on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I keep getting an error on one of my function.

this is the code:

```
const menu_item = document.querySelector('.header .nav-bar .nav-list ul li a');

menu_item.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
        mobile_menu.classList.toggle('active');
    });
});
```

This is the error it keeps throwing:
Uncaught TypeError: menu_item.forEach is not a function

Any help would be appreciated Thankss^^!!

Comment: use querySelectorAll

Comment: 'tis not an array, you're calling a singular element :)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you see ".forEach" is not a function, it means the object on which you're trying to use the method is not an array!

Why? Because ".querySelector" returns a single value, the first value that matches the selector.

You should use ".querySelectorAll" if you want to have a list!